# Find videos which are connected to several categories (1:N Relation) mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to select all videos, which are related (1:N Relation) to many categories. 
But finally I only want these videos, which are related to all given categories.

For example:

Request: cat[]=5&cat[]=6

Results: All videos, which are in category 5 AND 6

In fact I know how to handle this within 2 given categories (IN Statement, WHERE Exists etc). But we want to do it as dynamically as possible. Which means, that a customer is able to select about 30 categories at a time. 
I see a little bit of a performance issue in that case.
Currently I am handling these issue in PHP where I build several arrays, to validate each selected video (which results of an IN select) against each selected category.
But of course I have other problems with that. For example the pagination, limits etc. A lot of overhead I think.
My other idea was to create a cache_table, where the categories are concatenated and stored in an additional column which I would query with a INSTR or FULLTEXT search.

Does anybody know better ways to handle such a Query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a table with possible categories, a table with the videos, and a table which links the 2.

```
Categories    Videos              VideoCategories
1  cats       1 Cat being lazy    1 1
2  dogs       2 Dog barking       2 2
              3 Dog chasing Cat   3 1
                                  3 2
```

If you index those tables a query like the following is quite fast:

```
Select * from videos 
where videoId in 
  ( select videoId, count(*) numberOfMatches
    from VideoCategories 
    where categoryid in (1,2)
    group by videoId
    having numberOfMatches >= 2 )
```

I don't claim this is the fastest solution, but i think its a good way to get started, and its definitely faster than a fulltext search

Answer (score 0):

Since `IN ( SELECT ... )` is very poorly optimized, turn it into a JOIN:

```
Select  b.*
    from  videos b
    JOIN  
      ( SELECT  videoId, count(*) numberOfMatches
            from  VideoCategories
            where  categoryid in (5,6)
            group by  videoId
            having  numberOfMatches >= 2 
      ) a USING videoId;
```